# Differentiate transformed variables

Tags: derivatives, change-of-variable

I was reading [https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahhwi/LTCC/sectionB-similarity.pdf](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahhwi/LTCC/sectionB-similarity.pdf). The introduce new variable as for example $s=\varepsilon^b t$ and say that $\partial t = \varepsilon^b \partial s$. I think this is not true. If I interpret $s$ as a function of $t$, $s(t)=\varepsilon^b t$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}= \varepsilon^b
\end{align}
and so $\partial s=\partial t \varepsilon^b$. Then it should be $\partial t= \varepsilon^{-b} \partial s$.

Am I mistaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are actually right but are using a potentially sloppy notation. When they transform the heat equation
$$
\partial_t u=\kappa\,\partial_{xx}u
$$
to a new time variable $s=e^bt$ they introduce a new function $v(s,x)=u(t,x)=u(e^{-b}s,x)\,.$ By the chain rule $\partial_s v=\partial_t u\,e^{-b}\,.$ Therefore,
$v$ satisfies the equivalent heat equation
$$
e^{b}\partial_s v=\kappa\,\partial_{xx}v\,.
$$

Comment: Now it makes sense! Thanks