# Change of Variables - Writing the PDE in form of the new variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, canonical-transformation

In a script, the author brings in the canonical form the PDE in $\mathbb{R}^2$
$$
\partial_{x x} u-2 \partial_{x y} u-3 \partial_{y y} u+\partial_y u=0 .
$$
I only do not get this part:

> (...) Therefore, the desired change of variables is
> $$
> x^{\prime} =x, \qquad
> y^{\prime} =\frac{1}{2} x+\frac{1}{2} y
> $$
> Under this change we have
> $$
> \partial_{x x} u-2 \partial_{x y} u-3 \partial_{y y} u=\partial_{x^{\prime} x^{\prime}} u-\partial_{y^{\prime} y^{\prime}} u
> $$
> and
> $$
> \partial_y u=\frac{\partial x^{\prime}}{\partial y} \partial_{x^{\prime}} u+\frac{\partial y^{\prime}}{\partial y} \partial_{y^{\prime}} u=\frac{1}{2} \partial_{y^{\prime}} u .
> $$

How does he get the right hand sides of each part? Somehow the chain rule is used but I do not get the logic and the arithmetic behind the calculations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4659703/949989). Take as hint. Try your luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the transformation $\xi=x,\eta=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y$

we get the differential operators (using the chain rule)

$$\partial_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}}\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}}\frac{\partial{\eta}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}}$$

$$\partial_y=\frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}}\frac{\partial{\eta}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}}$$

$$\partial{x x}=(\frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}})^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\xi^2}}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\xi}\partial{\eta}}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\eta^2}}$$

$$\partial{y y}=(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}})^2=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\eta^2}}$$

$$\partial{x y}=(\frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}})\cdot(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\xi}\partial{\eta}}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\eta^2}}$$

Putting all together we finally get the transformed PDE
$$(\partial{x x}-2\partial{x y}-3\partial{y y}+\partial{y})\cdot u(x,y)=(\partial{\xi \xi}-\partial{\eta \eta}+\frac{1}{2}\partial{\eta})\cdot u(\xi,\eta)=0$$

$$u_{\xi \xi}-u_{\eta \eta}+\frac{1}{2}u_{\eta}=0$$